# NSLocalizedString - Force country specific string file

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

We are facing a strange behaviour with the handling of NSLoaclizedString with our bundle strings file.

We have maintained our strings file in:

- de_AT (german in Austria)
- de_DE (german in Germany)

We didn't setup any base/default strings file since we usually wan't to define per region which strings file should be used. So

- Region Poland should use de_DE
- Region Italy should use de_AT

During our tests we just recognized that NSLocalizedString just takes the first bundle (de_AT) independant of any Locale if the locale doesn't match.
Is there any way to define/control for which Locale we want to see the translations?

We only found a parameter "tableName" for the language, but no language & country specific locale... we don't want to create Localizable.strings for every available combination of language & country.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok we researched a lot, our current solution is to create independant Localizable.strings file and name them per locale:

- de_AT.strings
- de_DE.strings

Based on our mapping logic we do then set the right bundleName...